# SSH SOCKS5 Tunnel forwarding to reverse ssh host

Tags: ssh-tunnel, socks

I have the following machines

- **MachineA** behind firewall somewhere at the world
- **MachineB** server on the internet (middleman)
- **My Laptop** behind firewall somewhere at the world

**MachineA** maintains a reverse SSH tunnel to **MachineB**

```sh
machineA:> autossh -M 2000 -N MachineBIP -R 22000:localhost:22 -C
```

**My Laptop** can create a SOCKS5 tunnel to **MachineB**

```sh
my_laptop:> ssh -C2qTnN -D 8123 MachineBIP
```

Now obviously my browser goes out through MachineB. How can I extend the tunnel so it goes out from MachineA so the browser on My Laptop can access the network of MachineA?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is the following.

On your laptop, using the ssh config file `~/.ssh/config`.

1. Make sure both MachineA and MachineB have the pub key of your laptop in their authorised keys list.
2. Create the entries in the `config` for both machines. Write the entry MachineA as if you were calling it from MachineB after ssh -R was established.

```
Host machineB
    user root
    HostName _machineB_ip
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host machineA
    user root
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    Port 22000
```

3. Then use the `-J` parameter to identify a jumphost

```sh
ssh -J machineB -C2qTnN -D 8123 machineA
```